# Laravel hasMany sub-query

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a laravel hasMany relationship and I want to fetch the last 10 comments from a table and order them in descending order. 
This is how my table looks like

```
id  |   user_id |   comment_text
----------------------------------------------------------
1       30          foo
2       23          bar
3       17          hello
4       30          world
5       12          lorem
6       10          ipsum
7       17          dummy
```

My results should be

```
id  |   user_id |   comment_text
----------------------------------------------------------
5       12          lorem
6       10          ipsum
7       17          dummy
```

How I'm running the query to get the expected results

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```

How can I do this in a laravel model? Can I run a subquery in a relationship? This is my implementation so far

```
public function latestComments($limit = 3)
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)     
      ->orderByDesc('id')
      ->limit($limit);
  }
```

Comment: why that subquery its not needed .

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi Why? I have edited the code to show my expected results

Comment: use scope `https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#local-scopes`

Comment: @sammyukavi you can use either solution btl or mine, btl answer is considered as a better practice

Comment: I appreciate the solutions but none is giving the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. Using Laravel's `reverse`function I'm able to get the desired results all I need to do is call `reverse` on the property.

```
$post->latestComments->reverse()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right path, just correct it a bit:

```
public function latestComments($limit = 3)
{
     return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)     
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->take($limit);
}
```

You can read more of `take` and `orderBy` up on [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts and hate to say this but please see my expected results

Comment: You just need to update `$limit` to be 3 instead of 10 as you posted, i've updated the answer